# MySQL - Quais tipos de dados devem estar entre aspas?

Tags: mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um script para *backup/dump* do meu banco de dados via *PHP*, mas ao salvar o arquivo, preciso colocar, ou não, as aspas conforme o tipo da coluna.

Até aí tudo bem! Mas quais os tipos de dados que devem estar entre aspas?

Exemplo:

- **Inteiro**: `123` - `INT()`
- **String**: `'123'` - `VARCHAR()`

Preciso de uma lista completa dos tipos de dados e que diga se devem estar ou não entre aspas, e não achei uma lista satisfatória em minhas buscas.

Um exemplo mais detalhado de onde quero chegar:

```
mysql> explain teste;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| controle  | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| inteiro   | int(1)       | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| flutuante | float        | NO   |     | 0.1                 |                |
| string    | varchar(150) | NO   |     | fubá                |                |
| datahora  | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

No arquivo final (*dump*), as linhas para inserir os dados dessa tabela fica assim:

```
INSERT INTO `teste` VALUES (1,0,0.1,'fubá','0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Repare que os tipos `INT` e `FLOAT` não estão entre aspas. Já os tipos `VARCHAR` e `DATETIME` estão entre aspas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os dados do tipo numérico **não precisa** de aspas, já os dos tipos data/hora e cadeia (string) *precisam* ser definidos com aspas!

Dentre os principais:

**SEM ASPAS *(Numéricos)***: `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `MEDIUMINT`, `INT`, `INTEGER`, `BIGINT`, `FLOAT`, `DOUBLE`, `DOUBLE PRECISION`, `REAL`, `DECIMAL` e `NUMERIC`.

**COM ASPAS *(Data/hora e cadeia)***: `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TIME`, `YEAR`, `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TINYBLOB`, `TINYTEXT`, `BLOB`, `TEXT`, `MEDIUMBLOB`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, `LONGBLOB`, `LONGTEXT`, `ENUM` e `SET`.

Tem todos na [Documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) (em inglês).