# recebendo campo nulo ou ão nulo

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho um objeto de classe que aparece assim no `print_r();`

```
Membros Object
(
    [idMembro:Membros:private] => 
    [dataCadastro:Membros:private] => 2019-01-10
    [nome:Membros:private] => Cleonice P
    [apelido:Membros:private] => cleo
    [dataNascimento:Membros:private] => 1974-10-03
    [telefone:Membros:private] => 3237216149
    [celular:Membros:private] => 32988518043
    [bairro:Membros:private] => São Francisco
    [endereco:Membros:private] => Rua Francisco
    [email:Membros:private] => cleo@oi.com
    [sexo:Membros:private] => Masculino
    [estadoCivil:Membros:private] => Solteiro
    [dataBatismo:Membros:private] => 2019-01-09
    [bloqueado:Membros:private] => n
    [batizadoFora:Membros:private] => n
    [usuario:Membros:private] => caca
    [senha:Membros:private] => aaaa
)
```

Mas dataBatismo,

```
[dataBatismo:Membros:private] => 2019-01-09
```

Pode ocorer de vir vazia,

```
[dataBatismo:Membros:private] =>
```

Tenho a função abaixo que popula a tabela de membros

```
public function cadastrar( $Membro ) {

    $dataBatismo = empty($Membro->getDataBatismo()) ? "NULL" : $Membro->getDataBatismo();

    $string = "INSERT INTO membros (     
                     dataCadastro,
                     nome,
                     apelido,
                     dataNascimento,
                     telefone,
                     celular,
                     bairro,
                     endereco,
                     email,
                     sexo,
                     estadoCivil,
                     dataBatismo,
                     bloqueado,
                     batizadoFora,
                     usuario,
                     senha) 
                    VALUES (
                       '" . $Membro->getDataCadastro() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getNome() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getApelido() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getDataNascimento() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getTelefone() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getCelular() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getBairro() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getEndereco() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getEmail() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getsexo() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getEstadoCivil() . "',
                       " . $dataBatismo . ",
                       '" . $Membro->getBloqueado() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getBatizadoFora() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getUsuario() . "',
                       '" . $Membro->getSenha() . "'
                       )";
print "<pre>";
print_r($string);   
print "</pre>";
    return $this->conexao->query( $string ) == true ? true : false;

}
```

O problema está aqui aqui:

```
$dataBatismo = empty($Membro->getDataBatismo()) ? "NULL" : $Membro->getDataBatismo();
```

Mais precisamente aqui:

```
$Membro->getDataBatismo();
```

Quando a data não vazia, então acaba dando problema aqui,

```
" . $dataBatismo . ",
```

Que fica uma ***não string*** na `query` e só pode ser nula ou então string date

```
2019-10-01,
```

Quando o correto seria:

```
"2019-10-01",
```

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Se é uma string, por que ela não possui as aspas simples assim como todas as outras colunas da sua tabela?

Comment: Iria fazer a mesma observação. Já que data nascimento aparentemente dá certo, data batismo também deveria estar na mesma sintaxe. Dá uma olhada se é a falta de aspas simples na montagem da string.

Comment: porque se ela estiver nula, não pode ir com aspas para a query senão NÃO vai funcionar No entanto, se NÃO for nula, precisa das aspas mas fiz algumas tentativas de adiconar as aspas apenas quando não for nula e nenhuma deu certo.

Comment: Mas você já jogou o `NULL` entre aspas. Vai acabar resultando em uma *string* de qualquer jeito: `[...] mo()) ? "NULL" : "$Membr [...]`. Aliás, seu *getter* já deveria estar preparado para retornar `NULL` em campos vazios.

Comment: Quando o "NULL" que ainda está no PHP chegar na SQL ele se transfoma em NULL sem as aspas lá. Po causa da concatenação              " .  $dataBatismo . "

Comment: Lhe seria útil uma resposta que corrigisse TODO esse código postado?

Comment: Faz sentido @LipESprY, porque o ideal seria utlizar PDO

Comment: @PauloWeverton Justamente. Na real, eu não sei oq ele usa. Mas é orientado a objetos. Pode ser mesmo o PDO com o método `query()` ou o MySQLi com o método `query()`... Minha ideia é transformar essa query em prepared statement.

Comment: Isso. A montagem da consulta ficaria mais organizada e não teria esse tipo de problema que ele busca a solução

Comment: sim LipESprY , seria

Comment: @CarlosRocha Tudo bem. Vou formular uma resposta e já retorno.

Comment: mas no sistema todo eu não uso PDO pois só trabalho com mysql. Mais especificamente mysqli

Comment: PDO aceita MySQL e vários outros tipos de banco de dados. MySQLi, ao contrário, só funciona com MySQL (ou mariadb que dá no mesmo)...

Comment: vou ter que estudar  um pouco sobre PDO ainda. Mas obrigado!

Comment: @PauloWeverton dá uma olhada na minha resposta e veja se tem algo a mais para complementar. Vlw!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem, basta incluir aspas simples quando o valor não estiver vazio:

```
$dataBatismo = empty($Membro->getDataBatismo()) ? "NULL" : "'" . $Membro->getDataBatismo() . "'";
```

> **NOTA:** não sei de onde vêm os dados que vcoê usa nessa query, mas concatenar os valores sem tratamento pode criar [problemas de segurança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php). Recomendo usar *prepared statements*.

Comment: exato. Obrigado, deu certo!

Comment: eu estou gravando um novo membro. Então, e pego esses campos do formulário e envio eles para um script php que vai receber o form via ajax e vai criar um objeto da classe Membro que vai inserir no banco via método de uma classe que só faz cadastros e updates. Ou seja tudo em OO.

Comment: Não importa se é OO, você está montando a query na mão com dados potencialmente inseguros. Use *prepared statements*, a pergunta que eu linkei mostra como.

Answer (score 2):

Para começar, precisamos entender que:

- `null` ou `NULL` são nulos e pronto - Veja a documentação: [PHP - NULL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.null.php);
- `"null"` ou `"NULL"` ou `'NULL'` são *strings* com valor `null`/`NULL` - Veja a documentação: [PHP - Strings](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php);

Veja:

```
var_dump(null); // Retorna: NULL
var_dump('null'); // Retorna: string(4) "null"
```

Isso é válido tanto para o *PHP* quanto para o *MySQL* (veja [tipos de dados do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html)), que é o db em questão.

Veja o teste:

```
$null = null;
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `teste_null` VALUES ('".$null."');");
// > SELECT * FROM `teste_null`;
// +--------+
// | coluna |
// +--------+
// |        | // string vazia: ''
// +--------+

$null = "null";
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `teste_null` VALUES ('".$null."');");
// > SELECT * FROM `teste_null`;
// +--------+
// | coluna |
// +--------+
// | null   | // null
// +--------+
```

---

Veja:

```
$dataBatismo = empty($Membro->getDataBatismo()) ? "NULL" : $Membro->getDataBatismo();
```

Em tese, adicionar as aspas tanto na *query* quanto na coalescência, vai resolver o problema em questão. Mas, pera lá! Tem como melhorar e muito seu código.

Como dito, o MySQL pode guardar o `null` como *string* quando você guardar estes dados, já que está entre aspas. Dessa forma, você não vai poder validar tais informações usando as funções `empty()`, `is_null()` e afins.

Quando você menos perceber, você já vai ter uma bomba em suas mãos. Aprofunde-se nisso de forma que evite futuras manutenções por conta de má-prática de algo tão simples de contornar.

Vamos começar a corrigir seu código!

---

Veja, novamente, isto:

```
$dataBatismo = empty($Membro->getDataBatismo()) ? "NULL" : $Membro->getDataBatismo();
```

Poderia, facilmente, vir pronto do seu *getter*:

```
public function getDataNascimento()
{
    if (empty($this->dataNascimento))
        return null;
    else
        return $this->dataNascimento;
    /* Ou
    return (
        empty($this->nascimento)
        ? null
        : $this->nascimento
    ); */
}
```

Seria bom, também, padronizar seu *setter*:

```
public function setDataNascimento($valor)
{
    if (empty($valor))
        $this->dataNascimento = null;
    else {
        // Validações entram aqui
        $this->dataNascimento = trim($valor);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Isso é válido para todas as propriedades da sua classe.

---

Agora, deve-se corrigir, também, a sua *query*. Nada de aspas nela! No máximo, que eu recomendo, é usar a crase para evitar que use alguma palavra reservada do *MySQL*. Já deve ter ouvido este ditado:

> "*- É melhor ter e não precisar do que precisar e não ter...*"

Para tal feito, vou fazer um exemplo utilizando o *PDO*. Claro, pode fazer com o *MySQLi* também. Mas eu vou fazer meu exemplo com o *[PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)*. Tenho mais intimidade com ele, uai!

Suponhamos que a variável `$pdo` seja um objeto da classe `\PDO`. Vulga **[conexão com o db](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.construct.php)**:

```
// Montando a query:
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `membros` (
    `dataCadastro`, `nome`, `apelido`, `dataNascimento`,
    `telefone`, `celular`, `bairro`, `endereco`, `email`,
    `sexo`, `estadoCivil`, `dataBatismo`, `bloqueado`,
    `batizadoFora`, `usuario`, `senha`
) VALUES (
    :dataCadastro, :nome, :apelido, :dataNascimento,
    :telefone, :celular, :bairro, :endereco, :email,
    :sexo, :estadoCivil, :dataBatismo, :bloqueado,
    :batizadoFora, :usuario, :senha
);';

// Preparar a query:
$pdo->prepare($sql);

// "bindar" os valores na query
$pdo->bindValue(':dataCadastro', $Membro->getDataCadastro());
$pdo->bindValue(':nome', $Membro->getNome());
$pdo->bindValue(':apelido', $Membro->getApelido());
$pdo->bindValue(':dataNascimento', $Membro->getDataNascimento());
$pdo->bindValue(':telefone', $Membro->getTelefone());
$pdo->bindValue(':celular', $Membro->getCelular());
$pdo->bindValue(':bairro', $Membro->getBairro());
$pdo->bindValue(':endereco', $Membro->getEndereco());
$pdo->bindValue(':email', $Membro->getEmail());
$pdo->bindValue(':sexo', $Membro->getsexo());
$pdo->bindValue(':estadoCivil', $Membro->getEstadoCivil());
$pdo->bindValue(':dataBatismo', $Membro->getDataNascimento());
$pdo->bindValue(':bloqueado', $Membro->getBloqueado());
$pdo->bindValue(':batizadoFora', $Membro->getBatizadoFora());
$pdo->bindValue(':usuario', $Membro->getUsuario());
$pdo->bindValue(':senha', $Membro->getSenha());

// retorna true se tudo ocorrer bem ou false se ocorrer algum erro
return $pdo->execute();
```

Eu acho elegante utilizar o método `bindValue()`. Mas você pode utilizar uma matriz associativa como argumento do método `execute()`:

```
$pdo->execute(
    array(
        ':dataCadastro' => $Membro->getDataCadastro(),
        ':nome' => $Membro->getNome(),
        ':apelido' => $Membro->getApelido(),
        ':dataNascimento' => $Membro->getDataNascimento(),
        // ...
    )
);
```

A diferença, basicamente, é que o método `bindValue()` aceita tipagem:

```
$pdo->bindValue(':dataCadastro', $Membro->getDataCadastro(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo->bindValue(':nome', $Membro->getNome(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo->bindValue(':apelido', $Membro->getApelido(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
//...
```

Veja os tipos na documentação: [PHP - PDO: Constantes pré-definidas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.constants.php)

Repare que não utilizei aspas em nenhuma das colunas da tabela. O MySQL vai se encarregar de fazer tudo por você. Apenas lembre-se de que `NULL` é NULO (vazio, não definido, ausente) e `"NULL"` é uma *string* com valor `NULL`.

> Leitura recomendada: [MySQL - Quais tipos de dados devem estar entre aspas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201088/mysql-quais-tipos-de-dados-devem-estar-entre-aspas)

Comment: Também recomendo usar prepared statements, mas sua afirmação de que o código dele insere null como string não procede.

Comment: Opa, posso estar enganado. Mas acredito que já tenha me acontecido isso. Vou confirmar e já dou um retorno.

Comment: @bfavaretto Realmente você estava certo em parte. Editei a resposta. Olha lá. No PDO eu sempre atribuo `NULL` em campos vazios: `$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS,\PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);`

Comment: Essa resposta resolve da melhor forma